# spacemacs indent when I press 'o' after "for"

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Make an example,when I press 'o' at line 3 of java

```
public int maximumProduct(int [] nums)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++)

}
```

and I press '{' to make a block, the ident will be like this

```
public int maximumProduct(int [] nums)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++)
        {

        }
}
```

look that, the braces is look embarrassed. what could I do to solve this problem in spacemacs? If you know please leave a comment, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a whole lot of information, but try pressing `ctrl-c .`, which runs the command `c-set-style`, when you're in the buffer containing your Java code and pick anything besides `gnu`.  (I like `linux`.)

To learn more, you can use Emacs's built-in help function (`SPC h d f c-set-style` for spacemacs) or check the wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC

Comment: There to way to express a block with "{}": use for and '{' in the same line or use '{' at second line. This spacemacs configuration must have some mistakes, I can't use the secend way. I need to adust it on hand, it's not convenient.

Comment: The ```c-set-style``` command is what controls where the ```{``` on the second line is indented to.  As far as I know, all of them but the ```gnu``` setting don't indent the ```{``` on the second line.  Setting up something in your configuration like it shows [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc11) would be a more permanent fix, but just running the ```c-set-style``` command and changing it should work to see which style you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, Thanks for your comment. ^_^